# Usage of '=>' symbol on Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

I am a newbie to haskell and have a working code below as follows.

```
sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' [] = 0  
sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs
```

What i try to do is to be more specific about my types.Instead of using 'a' only i try to write my code like that.

```
sum' :: (Num a, Num b) => [a] -> b
sum' [] = 0  
sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs
```

When i do is i get an error.Error is as follows: Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for sum' :: (Num a, Num b) => [a] -> b
          at baby.hs:2:9
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for sum' :: (Num a, Num b) => [a] -> b
          at baby.hs:2:9

I think i don't really understand the meaning of '=>'. The part confuses me is what comes before '=>'. Sometimes a thing like that '(Show a) =>' and usually just types just like in my code. Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: The source of errors is that `+`'s type signature is `Num a => a -> a -> a`, i.e. it returns value of the same type as its arguments. But you want it to produce a value of a different type than it's arguments (`b` against `a`s), which it simply cannot do.

Comment: You are actually being *less* specific about your types. `[a] -> b` means you have no idea what type is being returned; the caller can specify anything they want. With `[a] -> a`, you are at least saying that the return type must be the same as the type stored in the input list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Instead of using 'a' only i try to write my code like that.

This doesn't work because `+` requires two arguments of the same type, and returns a result of that very type.

```
:t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Since there's no way to add two `Integer`s and get back a `Double`, or add an `Integer` and a `Double`, there is also no way to sum a list of `Integer`s and get back a `Double`.

`Num a =>` means that the type `a` must be a number. More precisely, it requires that there is an *instance* `Num a` of the *type class* `Num` exists.

More info about type classes can be found [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses)

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, you're saying "Take a list of `a`s (that are an instance of typeclass Num), and return something that's the same type as the elements in that list (that type is represented by `a` in the entire type signature)."  That's what you want.

The second snippet says "Take a list of `a`s (that are an instance of typeclass Num), and return something of type `b`, a different type."  Since (+) returns the same type as its parameters, your function must as well.

The `Num a` in your first snippet applies to all `a`s in the type signature, so there's no reason to split them into `a` and `b`.